# Postgres Vacuumdb sql

Tags: postgresql

Im using my localhost to try and vacuumdb from java using create statement.  I try to run the psql syntax in linux command line to verify if the syntax is indeed correct:

```
wsemp=# vacuumdb -d wsemp -z -v -h localhost -U jboss;
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "vacuumdb"
LINE 1: vacuumdb -d wsemp -z -v -h localhost -U jboss;
```

I tried almost everything by removing some options and changing it to this:

```
wsemp=# vacuumdb --host=127.0.0.1 --port=5432 --dbname=wsemp --username=dbauser --analyze --verbose;
```

but the same error shows up.  Any idea as to why?

Comment: Even running 'vacuumdb --analyze wsemp;' doesnt work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`vacuumdb` is the command-line tool. The sql command is `VACUUM`. The syntax for options is a bit different: [this is the documentation for it](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-vacuum.html).

I'm guessing from the arguments you pass to `vacuumdb` that you'd want something like:

```
wsemp=# VACUUM (VERBOSE, ANALYZE);
```